# I need information on how to configure the Google Speech-To-Text API to generate the output format as either .vtt or .srt subtitles file type

Tags: file, format, subtitle, video-subtitles

I could produce the output of an audio file but it came as a JSON type of file. I was informed that it is possible to configure the API to produce the file as .srt or .vtt which are adequate for being used to subtitle a video.
It seems that the API has a parameter called "output_format" that controls the property of the file it delivers.
However, I am unable to find the route to configure such parameter.

I did a lot of searching an even asked Bard, to no avail